# Centering Div while being able to expand div

Tags: html, css

I found this solution to centering my div vertically and horizontally. However if I fill in the content section past the length defined for the div it will run outside of it. I was hoping to make it expand depending on the content inside the div. How do I make it so this can happen?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/otacon6530/k5YUu/3/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headerwrapper">
            <div id="header" class="center">header</div>
        </div>
        <div id="titlewrapper">
            <div id="title" class="center">title</div>
        </div>
        <div id="contentwrapper">
            <div id="content" class="center">content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br>content<br></div>
        </div>
        <div id="footerwrapper">
            <div id="locationwrapper">
                <div id="location" class="center">location</div>
            </div>
            <div id="copyrightwrapper">
                <div id="copyright" class="center">copyright</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.center {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
    max-width: 5em;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#headerwrapper {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
#header {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#titlewrapper {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
#title {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#contentwrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
#content {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#locationwrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
#location {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
#footerwrapper {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#copyrightwrapper {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
#copyright {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: You can't have fixed height and the element to have height depending on the content via means of pure CSS/HTML. And also, consider pointing out what div you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "content" sections to dynamically adjust height, take off the fixed height.

Change:

```
#contentwrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8em;
}
```

To:

```
#contentwrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Working fiddle to your requirement: http://jsfiddle.net/k5YUu/6/